# ProcessBuilder cannot find sh file in resources folder - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, processbuilder

I have searched for a solution for a while on the internet but none give a clear image of how the sh file will be executed.

I have a shell script `install.sh` which I have kept in the `resources` directory. I want to run this from ProcessBuilder. No matter what I try, I keep getting a `No such file or directory` error. This is my code:

```
String masterURL = config.getMasterUrl();
String adminToken = config.getAdminToken();

ProcessBuilder installScriptBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
installScriptBuilder.command("install.sh", dir, namespace);
installScriptBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

Map<String,String> installEnv = installScriptBuilder.environment();
installEnv.put("URL", masterURL);
installEnv.put("TOKEN", adminToken);

try {
    Process p = installScriptBuilder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have read about creating a temporary file in other answers but none clearly show how to solve this problem with that. I have used Spring Initializr for creating my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select resource files with "classpath:install.sh".

In this case we can´t do that. We need the path itself:

```
final ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    final File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("install.sh").getFile());
    final ProcessBuilder installScriptBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    installScriptBuilder.command(file.getPath());
```

Comment: Cannot run program "classpath:install.sh": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tested this idea?

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava I wasn't talking to you.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "install.sh" (in directory "classpath:install.sh"): error=2, No such file or directory;

After adding the directory

Comment: Now I am getting a permission denied error: `Cannot run program "/home/piyush/workspace/service/target/classes/install.sh": error=13, Permission denied`

Comment: This is a problem of your script itself, i assume you want to write on a certain directory with it? Then you need to have writing rights on this directory. Please check if you have the permission to write in the directories!

Comment: `echo "++++Setting up context++++"`. This is what my script has.

Comment: Changing file permissions made it work! Thank you  for the help with finding the path.

Answer (score 1):

Resources are on the class path, typically zipped into the jar, and hence read-only, and not a File on the file system.

Use the resource as *template* to copy it to the file system.

```
Path path = dir.toPath().resolve("install.sh"); // dir a File
Path path = Paths.get(dir, "install.sh"); // dir a String
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/install.sh");
Files.copy(in, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: I copied the file in /tmp directory. I can see that it got copied in the file system. Then I set `installScriptBuilder.directory(new File("/tmp"));` .. But still getting the same error... `Cannot run program "install.sh" (in directory "/tmp"): error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: File rights (`chmod`) & file owners (`chown`)? Though /tmp typically has rights drwxrwxrwxt.

Comment: The script has -rw-rw-r-- . Though I have made the original script in `resources` executable. How can I make the new file executable and accessible to java?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this one liner should work:

```
installScriptBuilder.command(new ClassPathResource("install.sh").getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

`resources` folder is not maintained in the target. It is maven's folder structure. You may want to take a look at `target` folder to understand where your `install.sh` file is located. It will be accessible on classpath's `root`.